# Does Whatsapp/Signal/Telegram have a backdoor access to my message which is a copy of my private encryption key?

Tags: encryption, whatsapp

Does Whatsapp/Signal/Telegram have a backdoor access to my message which is a copy of my private encryption key?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of your other closed question, except now it doesn't make sense. No, they do not have backdoor access. No, your message does not have your private key. Please read the FAQs on how they do encryption

Comment: I think what you need to ask is: how does their encryption work? That's easy to answer (lots written about it)